# Setting up CSS x and y from mutiple PHP echoed attributes with a loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css, user-interface

A quickie question for the experts,

I am producing a collaboration site letting users add stickies with text and move them around the screen. I have a database file storing text and coordinates (PHP/MySql) done through ajax and jquery/jquery UI. I am having some issues with getting the data out of the database and looping back into the page.

The data is looped into a div class (with x and y as attributes) and I am using a loop to get the x and y back and trying to apply them to the CSS. I have alerted out and I am getting the data, but I seem to have a problem applying it. I knew this project was going to well....thanks for your time.

here is what I am trying in code:

Basic PHP loop:

```
<?php

$get_textsticky_query = "SELECT * FROM textsticky 
                        WHERE user_id = $current_id 
                       AND project_id=$user_project_id";

$get_textsticky_result=mysql_query($get_textsticky_query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get_textsticky_result)){

echo '<div class="textsticky" x="'.$row['textsticky_x'].'" y="'.$row['textsticky_y'].'"><div class="textstickyvalueholder" contentEditable="true" textstickyid="'. $row['textsticky_id'] .'">'. $row['textsticky_text'] .'</div><button>Like</button></div>';
}

?>
```

Trying to apply to CSS with jquery:

```
 $(".textsticky").each(function(index){

 //store x, y from looped php
 var x = $(this).attr("x");
 var y = $(this).attr("y");

 //assign looped php to css
 $(this).css("left",x);
 $(this).css("top",y);

  });
```

Comment: You should use the prefix data- (data-x='value' and data-y='value') to your custom attributes according to w3c.

Answer (score 0):

To move the object around within the parent container, you need to set `positoon: relative;` within the css of `.textsticky`.

To move the object around the entire screen, you need to set `position: absolute;`.

Without changing the `position` property, the `left` and `top` values will do nothing.

Comment: the position was set to absolute. The strange thing about this code is it does work in a prototype I built but not here.

Comment: @sherwoodbear that's odd. The `absolute` positioning allows the object to move anywhere, you dont use a child element so I'm not sure why your code would not work outside the prototype. Not without seeing the entire code.

Comment: its strange gonna try my prototype code within my main development work. Hopefully it will spring out at me! thanks 4 the input

Answer (score 0):

```
get_textsticky_result=mysql_query($get_textsticky_query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get_textsticky_result)){
      $x = $row['textsticky_x'];
      $y = $row['textsticky_y'];
      echo '<div class="textsticky" style="left:'.$x.'px; top:'.$y.'px;" textstickyid="'.     
      $row['textsticky_id'] .'"><div class="textstickyvalueholder" contentEditable="true">'.  
      $row['textsticky_text'] .'</div><button>Like</button></div>';
 }
```

I can use looped PHP with x and y set within the div and returned to a results div with ajax, rather than setting x and y it with javascript, a simpler solution in hindsight.

Answer (score 0):

here's your jquery solution! =)

check out my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4mgVC/

html:

```
<div class="textsticky" data-x=50 data-y=50></div>
<div class="textsticky" data-x=100 data-y=100></div>
<div class="textsticky" data-x=150 data-y=150></div>​
```

css:

```
.textsticky{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#000000;
    width:10px;height:10px;
}​
```

js:

```
$(".textsticky").each(function(index){

 //assign looped php coordinates to css
 $(this).css("left",$(this).data("x")).css("top",$(this).data("y"));

});​
```